# On the relationship between the commutators of a Lie group and its Lie algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, lie-algebras

I was trying to teach myself some basic Lie theory, and I came across this statement [on Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Commutator.html), relating the commutator of a group, $\alpha\beta\alpha^{-1}\beta^{-1}$, to the commutator of its Lie algebra, $[A,B] = AB-BA$:

> For instance, let $A$ and $B$ be square matrices, and let $\alpha(s)$ and $\beta(t)$ be paths in the Lie group of nonsingular matrices which satisfy
>   $$\begin{align}
>   \alpha(0)=\beta(0)    &=    I    \\
>   \left.\frac{\partial\alpha}{\partial s}\right|_{s=0}    &=    A    \\
>   \left.\frac{\partial\beta}{\partial s}\right|_{s=0}    &=    B,
>   \end{align}$$
>   then
>   $$\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial s}\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\alpha(s)\beta(t)\alpha^{-1}(s)\beta^{-1}(t)\right|_{(s=0,t=0)}=2[A,B].$$

When I tried to derive this for myself, using the fact that
$$\left.\frac{\partial\alpha^{-1}}{\partial s}\right|_{s=0} = \left.-\alpha^{-1}\frac{\partial\alpha}{\partial s}\alpha^{-1}\right|_{s=0} = -A,$$
I expanded the expression to get
$$\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial s}\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\alpha\beta\alpha^{-1}\beta^{-1}\right|_{(s=0,t=0)}$$
$$=\left.\left( \frac{\partial\alpha}{\partial s}\frac{\partial\beta}{\partial t}\alpha^{-1}\beta^{-1} + \alpha\frac{\partial\beta}{\partial t}\frac{\partial\alpha^{-1}}{\partial s}\beta^{-1} + \frac{\partial\alpha}{\partial s}\beta\alpha^{-1}\frac{\partial\beta^{-1}}{\partial t} + \alpha\beta\frac{\partial\alpha^{-1}}{\partial s}\frac{\partial\beta^{-1}}{\partial t} \right)\right|_{(s=0,t=0)}$$
$$=AB - BA - AB + AB$$
$$=[A,B].$$

The difference is that the factor of 2 is missing. This seems to agree with [the lecture notes I found on MIT OCW](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-755-introduction-to-lie-groups-fall-2004/lecture-notes/), which state (in Ch. 2, PDF 1) that if $X, Y \in \mathfrak{g}$,

> $\exp(-tX)\exp(-tY)\exp(tX)\exp(tY) = \exp\{t^2[X,Y]+O(t^3)\}$.

Since this is not my area of expertise, I wanted to make sure I got things right before I contacted MathWorld about a typo. Have I done something wrong somewhere, or is the MathWorld statement actually an error?

Comment: Don't believe everything that Wolfram's minions tell you :-)

Comment: Ignoring terms of order 3 and higher, and inverting 1+X using the power series,

(1+A)(1+B)(1-A+A^2)(1-B+B^2) = (1 + (A+B) + AB) (1 - (A+B) + (A^2 + AB + B^2)) = 1 - (A+B)^2 + AB + A^2 + AB + B^2 = 1 - (A^2 + AB + BA + B^2) + 2AB + A^2 + B^2 = 1 + AB - BA
= 1 + [A,B].  So no factor of 2.

Comment: P.S. I have sent MathWorld a message about this.

Comment: @Rahul: I saw your recent meta thread and, looking at your question postings, realized that this discussion might have been the intended example.  I undeleted the answer which, after posting, seemed to fit better as a comment, being a short and basically single-bit YES or NO answer to a [verification-request].

Comment: @T..: Thanks for that! Yes, this is the question I meant, and  thanks for letting me know about the [verification-request] tag. I think your answer, by providing an independent derivation of the requested result, certainly contains more than a single bit of information... At least for [verification-request]-style questions, such posts should be valid answers.

Comment: That tag does not yet exist. I have been been mentioning it as one of many non-math-subject tags that the site could benefit from. Just one more reason to oppose the importation of the anti-metatag notions that are alleged to exist among the StackOverflow users.

Comment: @T..: I see. Well, for what it's worth, I agree with you; if the tags [reference-request] and [terminology] exist, I see no reason why [verification-request] shouldn't.

Comment: @Rahul: MathWorld did not change the '2'. What is the correct answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ignoring terms of order $3$ and higher, and inverting $1+X$ using the power series,

$$\begin{align}&(1+A)(1+B)(1-A+A^2)(1-B+B^2)\\
=\;& (1 + (A+B) + AB) (1 - (A+B) + (A^2 + AB + B^2))\\
=\;& 1 - (A+B)^2 + AB + A^2 + AB + B^2 \\
=\;& 1 - (A^2 + AB + BA + B^2) + 2AB + A^2 + B^2\\
=\;& 1 + AB - BA   \\
=\;& 1 + [A,B]\end{align}$$