# Why if $C(t)\equiv A(t)B(t)A^{-1}(t)B^{-1}(t)$ then $\dot C(0)=[M,N]$?

Tags: lie-algebras

We know that the commutator of a lie algebra is defined as $$[M,N]=MN-NM.$$
I have seen [On the relationship between the commutators of a Lie group and its Lie algebra.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7944/on-the-relationship-between-the-commutators-of-a-lie-group-and-its-lie-algebra) He has provided a proof for that. But I was reading the book [Lie Algebras: Finite and Infinite Dimensional Lie Algebras and Applications in Physics Pt. 1.](http://www.amazon.in/Lie-Algebras-Dimensional-Applications-Mathematical/dp/0444887768) In that book it is mentioned that if $C(t)=A(t)B(t)A^{-1}(t)B^{-1}(t)$ then $$ \dot{C}(0)=MN-NM,\ \text{where } M=\dot{A}(0)\ \text{and } N=\dot{B}(0) . $$
But while computing the derivative of $C(t)$ I am getting \begin{align*} C^\prime(t) & =A(t)^\prime B(t)A^{-1}(t)B^{-1}(t)+A(t)B(t)^\prime A^{-1}(t)B^{-1}(t)+A(t)B(t)A^{-1}(t)^\prime B^{-1}(t)+A(t)B(t)A^{-1}(t)B^{-1}(t)^\prime\\
C^\prime(0) &= M+N-M-N=0
\end{align*}
Will anybody please tell me where I am doing the mistake and how will I get the commutator relation.
[image: Second order approximation.]

Comment: The name you want to google is "Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff Formula"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to expand to *second order* in $t$.
Try writing e.g. $A(t) = e^{tM}  \approx I + tM + \frac{t^2}{2}M + ... $ and expand $ABA^{-1}B^{-1}$ to second order.

Comment: I have added the second order expansion, but still I am not getting.

Comment: Will you please give a more elaboration of your answer?

Comment: Expand $(I+tM+\frac{t^2}{2}M)(I+tN+\frac{t^2}{2}N)(I-tM+\frac{t^2}{2}M)(I-tN+\frac{t^2}{2}N)$ to second order in $t$.

Comment: The solution in your picture isn't correct. You can't drop the $\frac{t^2}2 M$-like terms in the brackets.

Comment: I am unable to get you. Will you please provide me the details?

Comment: Just do exactly what I said in my third comment. Treat it as a high school algebra exercise.